# Voltage divison across capacitor when one cell connection is removed

Tags: bms, cell-balancing

In this image, the voltage read across capacitor C1 and C2 is 3.5 V, which is normal.

When I remove the connection between resistor R1 and V1, then the voltage read by the IC across C1 and C2 fluctuates between 4 V and 3 V.  The sum is always 7 V (assuming no cell balancing happening).

Please help me to understand this behaviour.

[image: Schematic diagram]

Comment: Please explain why you would want to remove R1.

Answer (score 1):

By disconnecting R1 from V1 you essentially remove R1 from the circuit. So that leaves you with just C1 and C2 connected to your V2. Assuming C1 and C2 are equal, they would have equal voltage on them if measured with an ideal voltmeter (with infinite resistance) So any imperfection you might see is due to 'Cell balancing IC' doing its business. First, it obviously has some finite resistance when it measures the voltage, second, it probably does some other stuff which leads to charge leaking from the capacitors.

Anyway, what are you trying to do by removing R1? Is this to trick the balancing circuit in some way?